# war file deployment on tomcat 8.5

Tags: pkcs#7

I am using jenkins on centos 7 and building java spring build, here result and build is showing success but I am getting error :

> org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException:
>   The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context
>   path [/erp] but context failed to start

And at last:

> Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
>   Finished: FAILURE

I have tried war project working when i deploy directly on tomcat 8.5

Comment: what does this have to do with [tag:pkcs#7]?  There isn't anything related to cryptography here....

Comment: i am deploying war file on tomcat 8.5 on centos 7.6 . during building i am getting error msg. org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/erp] but context failed to start.

Comment: Ok, your comment is essentially exactly the same as what your question says, but none of that explains what the question has to do with the tag you chose, since the tag is related to cryptography, not tomcat, or application deployment failures, or really anything mentioned in the question.  You'll have a much better chance of getting help if you take some time to find some tags that actually match your issue.